# Member enum class of template type as function argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to create a template function that takes as argument, not the template type itself, but a member enum class of the template type. Is this possible?

The following code demonstrates what I want to achieve and I wonder if there is some template magic that can accomplish it for me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    enum class ID {a1, a2};

    static void f(ID id){
        switch(id){
        case ID::a1:
            std::cout << "a1\n";
            break;
        case ID::a2:
            std::cout << "a2\n";
            break;
        }
    }
};

class B{
public:
    enum class ID {b1};

    static void f(ID id){
        switch(id){
        case ID::b1:
            std::cout << "b1\n";
            break;
        }
    }
};

template<typename TypeName>
void g(TypeName::ID id){
    TypeName::f(id);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    g(A::ID::a1);
    g(A::ID::a2);
    g(B::ID::b1);

    return 0;
}
```

With the wanted output being

```
a1
a2
b1
```

In particular, note how I want the function g to take TypeName::ID as argument rather than TypeName.

A C++11 solution is preferred, but solutions that work with later versions are also of interest.

Comment: TypeName template parameter in 'g' is in non-deducible context, so the caller must specialize 'g' explicitly.  But note that you could make ID type itself a template parameter - why is it important that it's an inner type?

Comment: @IgorR. In the example I give above, g need to call a static function on TypeName. In the real example where I'm using it, my corresponding g needs to call another template function where TypeName is passed on as template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    enum class ID {a1, a2};

    static void f(ID id){
        switch(id){
        case ID::a1:
            std::cout << "a1\n";
            break;
        case ID::a2:
            std::cout << "a2\n";
            break;
        }
    }
};

class B{
public:
    enum class ID {b1};

    static void f(ID id){
        switch(id){
        case ID::b1:
            std::cout << "b1\n";
            break;
        }
    }
};

template<typename TypeName>
void g(typename TypeName::ID id){
    TypeName::f(id);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    g<A>(A::ID::a1);
    g<A>(A::ID::a2);
    g<B>(B::ID::b1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm.

Insight into what the typename in front of the argument does would be greatly appreciated. I have used typename in similar situations before, but never really understood what it does in this context.

Comment: I don't understand why the template argument deduction doesn't figure out what TypeName should be without having to explicitly supply it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name @Kristofer Björnsen

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction scroll down to non-deduced context @Jerry Jerimiah

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename TypeName>
void g(TypeName::ID id){ // WRONG
    TypeName::f(id);
}
```

requires `typename`:

```
template<typename TypeName>
void g(typename TypeName::ID id){
    TypeName::f(id);
}
```

but so, type is not deducible (because of the `::`).
so at call site, you have to specify the type:

```
g<A>(A::ID::a1);
g<A>(A::ID::a2);
g<B>(B::ID::b1);
```

As alternative, to keep your expected call site syntax, you might create trait to bind (enum) type to a class:

```
template <typename E> struct ClassFromId;

template <> struct ClassFromId<A::ID> { using type = A; };
template <> struct ClassFromId<B::ID> { using type = B; };


template<typename E>
void g(E id){
    ClassFromId<E>::type::f(id);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c64a67b6905e3b56)

Comment: Thanks for showing the alternative! It's not crucial for me to avoid the extra template parameter in the call, but it's very useful to know that it is possible.

I have one question. Can I rely on the last alternative to be a pure completely compile-time solution? For these particular classes, I am very sensitive to even small performance penalties.

It seems to me that "using type = A" is a compile-time property of a struct that never gets instantiated, and that no runtime instructions are generated from this code. But just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: The machinery to deduce class type from enum is compile time: No runtime penality.